# pass value to custom field in azure board task, user story etc

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, workitem

I have created a custom field on the ado board ,now I would like to pass value in to it using REST API, pls let me know if that is possible ?if so how? please look at the below screen shot for an example

[image]

How to pass value in to the custom field as highlighted in the screen shot via REST API

Comment: Please 1) turn off CAPS lock, 2) share the code you're having trouble with, and 3) describe what's not working and/or any error messages you're getting.

Comment: 1)caps are gone 2 ) as mentioned in the question ,created a custom field on the board which is highlighted in RED, how to pass values in to the field using REST API, is there a specific end point for populating values in to Custom Fields

Comment: "Custom_SysID": "xxxxxxxxx" FYI this is the underlying value of the field highlighted in red in the screenshot

Comment: The field name is `Custom.SysID` (i.e `.` rather than `_`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no custom endpoint for populating fields, they are part of the workitem endpoint on `_apis/wit/workitems` and can be passad along in the `POST` request when creating a workitem or updated through `PATCH` request

### Update the value of a field on an existing item

If you want to [update a field on an existing workitem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/update?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0#update-a-field), make a `PATCH` request to the following url

```
https://dev.azure.com/{{ORGANIZATION}}/_apis/wit/workitems/{{ID}}?api-version=6.0
```

With the following body (replace `{{FIELDVALUE}}` with the actual value you want to set). Fields not mentioned in the body will remain as is

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Custom.SysID",
    "value": "{{FIELDVALUE}}"
  }
]
```

### Set the field upon creation of the workitem

If you are [creating a workitem from scratch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wit/work%20items/create?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) you make a `POST` request to

```
POST https://dev.azure.com/{{ORGANIZATION}}/_apis/wit/workitems/Task?api-version=6.0
```

The body is on the same format, but may contain other fields that should be initialized (like title):

```
[
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/Custom.SysID",
    "value": "{{FIELDVALUE}}"
  },
  {
    "op": "add",
    "path": "/fields/System.Title",
    "value": "MyTitle"
  }
]
```